# pdo fetch query in class only returning one row

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

EDIT: THanks everyone for pointing out that i override the $Html variable. i've had a bit to drink tonight and missed that.

I'm working on my own custom forum for my website and for some reason or another the code is only returning one row. There's two "posts" on the forum, and only the lastest of them is being returned in when echoing the results of this function.

```
    function displayTopics($tid)
{
    $sql = "SELECT message_body, poster FROM thread_messages WHERE threadID = :tid";
    $que = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $que->bindParam(':tid', $tid);
    try{ 
        $que->execute();
        while($row = $que->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
        {
            $username = $this->getUsername($row->poster);
            $html = "<div class='message'>
                        <div class='userInfo'>
                            <img width='50' height='50' />
                            {$username}
                        </div>
                        <div class='body'>
                        {$row->message_body}
                        </div>
                    </div>";    
        }
    }catch(PDOException $e){}
                $html .= 
                "<form action='reply.php' method='post'><input type='hidden' name='tid' value='{$tid}'>".
                "<textarea name='replybody'>Reply...</textarea>".
                "<input type='submit' value='reply'>".
                "</form>";
                return $html;
```

}

Comment: You override your variable `$html` in your while loop

Comment: replace `$html = "<div class....` with `$html .= "<div class....`

Answer (score 0):

I messed up, my bad. the loop should've looked like this

```
        while($row = $que->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
    {
        $username = $this->getUsername($row->poster);
        $html .= "<div class='message'>
                    <div class='userInfo'>
                        <img width='50' height='50' />
                        {$username}
                    </div>
                    <div class='body'>
                    {$row->message_body}
                    </div>
                </div>";    
    }
```

I was overriding the $Html variable.